# What would be the most efficient way to search 3 tables and their related tables?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have three tables:

- Store (linked to address and category tables)
- Brand (linked to category table)
- Shopping mall (linked to address)

[image]

When I do a search for `ac`, I need to search each table and fetch all rows starting with `ac`.

I also need to fetch

- the address and categories for each store
- the address for each shopping mall
- the categories for each brand

My search is using autocomplete but I don't want to display the result in one big chunck, but rather divide the result in store, brand and shopping mal.

My current solution is to execute 3 separate SQL queries, and put the result in ann array and return this.

But I don't feel doing the query this way is the most efficient way. Is there a better way to increase the speed of my search? Is there a best practice for complex search?

I am indexing things like name and address.

Currently I can only use MySQL DB.

Comment: Unite your queries into one joined search,and add indexes where needed after an explain.You dont need full text search.

Comment: Just to clarify: If you search for `ac` you search brands, stores and shopping malls beginning with `ac`?

Comment: @Reeno yes and I'm not doing full text search. My service is based on fast search, so it needs to be, well, fast :) My DB is small now, but it will grow. And in time I might use something like ElasticSearch.

Comment: A brand doesn't have an address and a shopping mall doesn't have a category, so I think it's the best to do three queries and UNION them. In the query for the brands, add an empty column for address (`'-' AS address), same for malls and categories.

Comment: Hmm... okey. But if I do a union, how can I, in PHP, know that one row is a store and another row is a brand?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your exact table structure, I'd propose something similar to this:

```
SELECT
 stores.name AS name,
 addresses.street AS street,
 addresses.city AS city,
 'store' AS type,
 GROUP_CONCAT(categories.categoryname) AS category
FROM
 stores
INNER JOIN
 addresses ON addresses.addressid = stores.storeid
INNER JOIN
 categories AS categories.storeid = stores.storeid
WHERE
 stores.name LIKE "ac%"
GROUP BY
 stores.storeid
UNION
SELECT
 brands.name AS name,
 '-' AS street,
 '-' AS city,
 'brand' AS type,
 GROUP_CONCAT(brandcategories.categoryname) AS category
FROM
 brands
INNER JOIN
 brandcategories AS brandcategories.brandid = brands.brandid
WHERE
 brands.name LIKE "ac%"
GROUP BY
 brands.brandsid
UNION
SELECT
 malls.name AS name,
 addresses.street AS street,
 addresses.city AS city,
 'mall' AS type,
 '-' AS category
FROM
 malls
INNER JOIN
 addresses ON addresses.addressid = malls.mallid
WHERE
 malls.name LIKE "ac%"
GROUP BY
 malls.mallid
```

Do a `SELECT...` for each of the tables and UNION them. Each SELECT gets a column `type`, where type can be store, brand or mall. So you can distinguish it later in your PHP code.

Since every SELECT in a UNION needs the same columns, also the SELECT for e.g. brand returns an address, but it's empty.

In this example, every store/brand can have multiple categories, which get returned at once in a comma separated field (`GROUP_CONCAT(categories.categoryname)`).